# Text stroke line css

Tags: css

i wanted to ask how will i make my text like the one in the image? Can someone help me? Thank you. This is the code i did so far. but it doesnt look like same

This is my code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </head>
      <style>
        h2 {
          color: transparent;
          font-size: 3em;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: "Baloo";
          -webkit-text-stroke: 2pt #608b31;
        }
      </style>
    
      <body>
        <h2>Testing</h2>
      </body>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: [You don't need jQuery](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery). Remove that abomination from your HTML at once.

Comment: Also, you _really_ should host your own assets (JS, CSS, etc): otherwise you're just opening yourself up to future XSS vulnerabilities (no CDN will last forever - the `integrity` attribute helps but isn't a panacea). Due to privacy changes in browsers there's no performance benefit to using a shared CDN.

Comment: ohh okay okay  i understand. will remove

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: your `<html>` element can only have 2 children: `<head>` and `<body>` - you need to move your `<script>` and `<link>` elements to be in `<head>` (there's no need to put `<script>` at the end of `<body>`, put them in the `<head>` and use `defer`.

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` and `<link>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob In XHTML the self-closing slash is required. XHTML is still relevant in some applications where HTML needs to be well-formed for high-performance document processing by standard XML libraries.

Comment: @Dai He's not using XHTML.

Comment: @Rob I know, but I'm saying you're factually incorrect when you say those elements "do not need a closing slash **and never have in any HTML specification**" because XHTML **is** a member of the HTML specification family.

Comment: @Dai No it is not. XHTML is a member of the XML specification.

Comment: @Rob The XHTML specifications are not a part of XML. More precisely: _XHTML is an application of XML_. The XHTML specifications fall under the HTML umbrella at the W3C - not the XML area - this is stated as much in the abstract of the original XHTML 1.0 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/: "**This document has been produced as part of the W3C HTML Activity.**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Dai *More precisely: XHTML is an application of XML.* Thus proving my point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238241/discussion-between-dai-and-rob).

Comment: @Dai Let's not. I've already had this confirmed with W3C and WHATWG members years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack as many `text-shadow` elements as you like in a CSS rule. Although you'll never get perfect results with fonts that have sharp external angles, you can get near-perfect results with rounded sans-serif fonts like the one you're using:

```css
h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 6em;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Baloo";
  text-shadow: 0.000em 0.075em #608b31, 0.029em 0.069em #608b31, 0.053em 0.053em #608b31, 0.069em 0.029em #608b31, 0.075em 0.000em #608b31, 0.069em -0.029em #608b31, 0.053em -0.053em #608b31, 0.029em -0.069em #608b31, 0.000em -0.075em #608b31, -0.029em -0.069em #608b31, -0.053em -0.053em #608b31, -0.069em -0.029em #608b31, -0.075em -0.000em #608b31, -0.069em 0.029em #608b31, -0.053em 0.053em #608b31, -0.029em 0.069em #608b31;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo" rel="stylesheet">
<h2>Testing</h2>
```

The only problem you might have is that the text needs to be filled with a solid white colour. If you really need the text to be transparent inside the outline, then you'll have to use another method such as an SVG, as others have suggested.

I wrote a Python function to generate the shadow positions:

```py
def css_outline(num_points, radius, units, colour):
    from math import cos, sin, pi
    shadows = []
    for i in range(num_points):
        t = i * 2 * pi / num_points
        x = sin(t) * radius
        y = cos(t) * radius
        shadows.append("%.3f%s %.3f%s %s" % (x, units, y, units, colour))
    return (', '.join(shadows))
```

The CSS in the above example was generated by calling `css_outline(16, 0.075, 'em', '#608b31')`

Comment: Nice answer - and a really useful tool for creating the stacked shadows!

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get exactly the same as that image using the same font, because that reference looks to have the lines *outside* the text shape, rather than making the outline itself wider.

Basically, a font is just a vector shape. If you make the outline visible as you have, you can see what the shape is. What you can't do in CSS is to *change* that shape (e.g. make it "fatter" as in your reference image). Because the "outline" reference you're chasing has the lines *outside* the actual letter, you can't do what you want.

There are a couple of options, though. The first is to try different font weights (e.g. bold, black, exra-bold, whatever's available). These will have fatter characters, so the outline may produce a result closer to what you want (whether you use `-webkit-text-stroke` as in your original code or some variant on `text-shadow` as in the other answer).

The second is to use an SVG (or even PNG) image instead of real text. However, if you're using this for actual content on your page, you'll need to make sure you've properly provided accessible information (`alt` attributes for images) so that people using screen readers can still use your website.

Answer (score 1):

**try to do it with text-shadow...**

*here i'm adding 1px blue stroke*

```
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 blue, 1px -1px 0 blue, -1px 1px 0 blue, 1px 1px 0 blue;
```

Comment: `-webkit-text-stroke` is widely supported by all modern browsers (including Firefox and Safari), so I don't see the need to resort to abusing `text-shadow`.

Comment: @Dai Vendor prefixed properties should not be used at all when possible. Using them is an abuse, not using the standard property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Comment: @Rob Who, exactly, is saying vendor-prefixed properties "should not be used at all"? The W3C and MDN certainly _recommends_ not to, but they aren't issuing RFC-style prohibitions.

Comment: @Dai Added a link to my comment.

Comment: @Rob I'm familiar with MDN's guidance on vendor-prefixed properties - none of that article can be interpreted to mean using proprietary extensions is an "abuse". Whereas my use of the term "abusing" is in reference to the fact that `text-shadow` is not intended for stroking text outlines, whereas `webkit-text-stroke` _is_. All they have to say is "Developers should wait to include the unprefixed property until browser behavior is standardized." - I don't interpret that as a prohibition at all.

Comment: @Dai While I may have misread your previous statement, I did not say it was prohibited. Just saying one should not use them "if possible". In fact, such things will be hidden by flags in the user's browser at some point.

Comment: Arguing about the "proper" use of `text-shadow` isn't very productive. The name may imply a soft shadow, but it's designed specifically so as to allow hard outlines like this. But using `-webkit-text-stroke` should be approached with caution, in the knowledge that it's not a standard part of CSS, may not work in all browsers and may change or disappear at some point. Use the tool that gives the result you want IMO.

Comment: @JohnP "but it's **designed specifically** so as to allow hard outlines like this" - I disagree. [The spec for `text-shadow` cautions about various defined and undefined behavior](https://web.archive.org/web/20180623201858/https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/) in the spec which I interpret to mean it should not be used as a mechanism for general text path-stroking, e.g. "It is undefined whether a given shadow layer shadows each glyph or decoration independently or if the text and/or decorations are flattened and then shadowed." - that alone puts me off using it for stroking text.

Comment: I absolutely agree that `text-shadow` is not a general text-outlining tool, but the spec specifically allows a blur of 0, which produces a hard line, so it's hard to argue that one shouldn't use the property in this way. (In context, that "undefined" is the only thing undefined about `text-shadow`, and it appears to be undefined because it doesn't matter: shadows are not allowed to overlap other text elements at the same level, so whether glyphs are shadowed individually or flattened should produce the same result. But this is well out of scope of this answer. )